# Connectivity slowly decreases over minutes

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet

My PC is experiencing network issues over a wired connection (albeit via a Powerline).

Yesterday, web pages took ages to load, most timed out. I would occasional 'spikes' of connection which would last seconds at best.

I tried pinging a website by IP - many (most) packets were dropped.

So, I tried to ping my router and most packets were dropped. I tried from another computer and it connects fine. At this stage I thought it shows the router is OK so it must be the the cable or ethernet port on my PC.

I pulled the ethernet out of the back of the computer and plugged it back in. The network was up and responsive again. After 30 seconds -> 1 minute, the pages were taking longer to respond. After about 2 minutes, the pages were no longer responded.

I pulled the ethernet out of the back of the computer and put it back in again and the exact same behaviour occured. It was fine for a little while but the pages gradually took longer to 'fetch'.

This I think suggests the cable is OK... it is almost as if there is a build up of traffic  (like a queue) and the PC can't process it.

The PC is quite high spec for development and music production.

Just out of some voodoo fixing, I tried updating the DNS to use 8.8.8.8 incase it was an issue resolving, but this made no real difference (it took slightly longer for each web page)

I was testing with sites like Google searches/BBC website.

My own reading suggests that hardware typically works or doesn't work, so I don't think it's the cable nor router.

The ethernet driver is up to date. I am using

```
Interl(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection  
Driver: Intel
Driver version: 11.13.51.0
```

I've done a virus and malware scan.

I never get IP conflicts.

IP of computer is dynamic.

Another laptop plugged in works fine and does not experience this issue.

My questions is, how do I debug this issue?

Comment: First of all, please tell us what OS are you running, what network adapter are you using and the version of the driver would be useful too

Comment: From the description it sounds like driver problem could be the issue. It is worth trying different NIC if you have one available, or trying to boot into different OS

Comment: @smc, yes, good questions, I will post that answer in several few hours as I'm at work now. Sorry!

Comment: @Buscar웃 after a quick read up, it looks like that will be useful if I'm playing computer games or similar online - I'm not talking about those type of minor improvements, I'm talking about websites timing out over a great deal of time (many seconds). Do you still feel it's worth trying?

Comment: @Buscar웃, I'm sorry, I don't think your comments are useful. I've already explained that it fails at the router... what am I going to traceroute when it fails at the first point?!?!?